# R: Names of Columns | Subset | Warning Message

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a problem with the a subset I created. With this subset I can also not change the names of the columns and I don't know how to solve it. Here is, how I created the subset.

At the beginning I had a dataset like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = '
participant_nr condition used_hand value
01 B left 13
01 C left 20
01 A left 60
01 D left 11
01 E left 17
01 B right 18
01 C right 19
01 A right 23
01 D right 18
01 E right 15
02 C left 18
02 A left 7
02 B left 12
02 D left 11
02 E left 21
02 A right 17
02 B right 20
02 C right 21
02 D right 19
02 E right 15', header = T)
```

In the next step I excluded all conditions from my dataset where condition is A. Also I created 2 new factorial variables based on the condition. My code looked like this:

```
df_02 <- df %>%
  filter(! condition == "A")  %>%
  mutate(Side = case_when(
  condition %in% c("B", "C") ~ "left",
  condition %in% c("D", "E") ~ "right")) %>%
  mutate(Rotation = case_when(
  condition %in% c("B", "E") ~ "low",
  condition %in% c("C", "D") ~ "high")
    )

is.factor(df_02$Side) #FALSE
is.factor(df_02$Rotation) #FALSE
df_02_factor <- Data_Omnibus %>%
  convert_as_factor(Side, Rotation)
is.factor(df_02$Side) #TRUE
is.factor(df_02$Rotation) #TRUE
```

Since in the new subset the categorical variables are based only on condition and not on used_hand anymore, we have 2 values per participant for every combination of factors. If we would run an repeated-measure ANOVA on this, we would receive the following Error:

```
Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 396 rows
```

So I solved this problem with taking the mean of the two values for each combination of factorial variables in a new subset.

```
subset <- df_02_factor %>%
  group_by(participant_nr) %>%
  summarise( df_02_factor %>%
  group_by(ID, Side, Rotation) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars("value"), mean)
  )
```

After this I receive the following Warning Message:

```
In names(cols)[missing_names] <- names[missing_names] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Also, I cannot change the name of the columns or conduct an repeated-measure ANOVA. What went wrong here and how do I fix this? I need to conduct a repeated-measure ANOVA between Side, Rotation and value and this turns out to cause so many subproblems.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is convert_as_factor from the `rstatix` package or somewhere else?

Comment: It sounds like this might be more of a statistical methodology question than a programming one, so I wonder if https://stats.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate for this.

Comment: I think you're missing a paren to close out your first `summarise(df_02_factor %>%`, or something else, since that looks like incomplete/broken code. FYI, `summarise_at` (and similar verbs) has been superseded since Jan 2020 in favor of `across` and `pick`; migration is not difficult, and `across` is a very powerful mechanism, I suggest shifting towards its use.

Comment: Yes, `convert_as_factor` is from `rstatix`

Comment: I receive a dataset, which I can view with the correct values I whish to receive, but I cannot do anything further with it. My problem is, that I don't understand, why the output `subset` cannot be renamed with a standard code like `df <- rename(df, new_name = old_name)`.

Comment: @Jon Spring, you were right. The problem was that a parameter was missing in my statistical model.